# Recommendations for user 'levelling' system

Tags: php, ranking, achievements

I am looking for a, preferably open-source, user levelling/ranking system. By this I mean, similar to Xbox Live Achievements, users can complete a certain task, get awarded 'points' and then progress through 'levels'.

EDIT: An even better example is THIS site (is this user system open-source)!!

An example can be see at the top bar of this site, or the one below

http://www.1up.com/

Should ideally be PhP based.

Thanks in advance.
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [**Badgeville**](http://www.badgeville.com/).

Comment: Thank you, although there appears to be little info on the actual site (you have to contact them which i have done) it is along the right lines. 

It appears as if this will be a paid service, are you familiar with any open-source platforms or at least ones which offer a trial?

Answer (score 3):

Check out UserInfuser for an open source gamification platform: http://code.google.com/p/userinfuser

It has bindings for PHP, Python, Java, and Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

For other people interested in this there are also a few others:

BigDoor
BunchBall
uBoost

The general term for this sort of process is called 'Gamification'

Unfortunately there does not appear to be a open-source version yet.

Answer (score 2):

Of course I'll have to recommend you check out http://www.IActionable.com

Our API supports Achievements, Levels, Points and Leaderbords. We built a flexible rule engine and complex event processing system which supports simple or complex reward requirements. While not open-source, the API is a very easy to implement REST based service.

Answer (score 1):

We'd throw in BigDoor; our gamification platform is open, flexible, easy, secure and free! http://www.bigdoor.com/.  Our widget, the BigDoor MiniBar is white-labeled and takes minutes to add to any site.  You can check it out in action right now on Brad Feld's site: http://www.feld.com/wp/.